# When is the Github Projects beta slated for general release?

Tags: github

This is the feature that builds on the existing Project implementation but which adds support for custom metadata fields. E.g. Story Points and Priority, so it's a pretty big deal.

Having some idea of when it's due would give me a clue as to how much effort to put into exploring other options in the meantime.